# Altering one query parameter in a url (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a search page that takes a variety of parameters. I want to create a new URL by just altering one parameter in the query. Is there an easy way to do this - something like:

```
# example request url
http://example.com/search?q=foo&option=bar&option2=baz&change=before

# ideal template code
{% url_with change 'after' %}

# resulting url
http://example.com/search?q=foo&option=bar&option2=baz&change=after
```

So this would take the request url, alter one query parameter and then return the new url. Similar to what can be achieved in Perl's Catalyst using `$c->uri_with({change => 'after'})`.

Or is there a better way?

[UPDATED: removed references to pagination]

Comment: reformulate your question, it's not clear what you want, and try to accept answers, you have a ratio of 0%.

Comment: I have changed the question to remove the reference to pagination, which seemed to make people jump to give the answer to a question which was not asked. Will gladly accept a good answer as soon as there is one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So, write a template tag around this:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse
from django.http import QueryDict

def replace_query_param(url, attr, val):
    (scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment) = urlparse(url)
    query_dict = QueryDict(query).copy()
    query_dict[attr] = val
    query = query_dict.urlencode()
    return urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment))
```

For a more comprehensive solution, use Zachary Voase's [URLObject 2](https://github.com/zacharyvoase/urlobject), which is very nicely done.

**Note:**
The `urlparse` module is renamed to `urllib.parse` in Python 3.

Answer (score 26):

I did this simple tag which doesn't require any extra libraries:

```
@register.simple_tag
def url_replace(request, field, value):

    dict_ = request.GET.copy()

    dict_[field] = value

    return dict_.urlencode()
```

Use as:

```
<a href="?{% url_replace request 'param' value %}">
```

It wil add 'param' to your url GET string if it's not there, or replace it with the new value if it's already there.

You also need the RequestContext request instance to be provided to your template from your view. More info here:

http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/may/10/getting-requestcontext-your-templates/

Comment: Nice! And when you use `takes_context=True`, the request can be read via `context['request']`, assuming you have the `RequestContext` in use off course!

Comment: Good god, this ought to be included in Django itself. Very elegant solution.

Comment: Is it preferable to use `dict_.__setitem__(field,value)` over `dict_[field] = value` ? Django internally uses [`__setitem__()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1101467ce0756272a54f4c7bc65c4c335a94111b/django/http/request.py#L372) which does a `bytes_to_text` conversion

Comment: This is often enough because of relative query string paths: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291307/relative-url-containing-just-the-querystring

Comment: For some reason I didn't have to do any work to add the request context. I'm using Django 4.1.5.

Answer (score 10):

I improved mpaf's solution, to get request directly from tag.

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context = True)
def url_replace(context, field, value):
    dict_ = context['request'].GET.copy()
    dict_[field] = value
    return dict_.urlencode()
```

Comment: this one calls get_context_data twice. if you have some images to the database in get_context_data, they will be executed several times

Answer (score 4):

This worked pretty well for me.  Allows you to set any number of parameters in the URL.  Works nice for a pager, while keeping the rest of the query string.

```
from django import template
from urlobject import URLObject

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_set_param(context, **kwargs):
    url = URLObject(context.request.get_full_path())
    path = url.path
    query = url.query
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        query = query.set_param(k, v)
    return '{}?{}'.format(path, query)
```

Then in the template:

```
<a href="{% url_set_param page=last %}">
```

Comment: What is `URLobject`? Third party?

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 check it on: https://urlobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of template tags for modifying the query string djangosnippets.org:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/553/
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/826/
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1243/

I would say those are the most promising looking. One point in all of them is that you must be using `django.core.context_processors.request` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/dcramer/django-paging

Comment: The question is about altering a single parameter in a url, not about paginating.

Comment: Sorry. When i posted a link to paging, i mean to look at the code, where GET parameters are constructed. Sorry my english

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the snippets mentioned by Mark Lavin, Here's a list of other implementations I could find for a Django template tag which modifies the current HTTP GET query string.

On djangosnippets.org:

- [#2237 Manipulate URL query strings using context variables using a template tag](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2237/) by [JHsaunders](http://djangosnippets.org/users/JHSaunders/)
- [#2332 Querystring Builder - create urls with GET params](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2332/) by [jibberia](http://djangosnippets.org/users/jibberia/)
- my favorite: [#2413 Yet another query string template tag](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2413/) by [atms](http://djangosnippets.org/users/atms/)
- [#2428 Add GET parameters from current request](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2428/) by [naktinis](http://djangosnippets.org/users/naktinis/)

On PyPI:

- [django-spurl](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-spurl/) by [Jamie Matthews](https://github.com/j4mie)
- [django-urltags](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-urltags/) by [Calloway Project](http://callowayproject.com/)/[Corey Oordt](https://github.com/coordt)
- the [add_query_param](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/863bbe7684c44921b779a69c6b4c2ff16a223bd8/djangorestframework/templatetags/add_query_param.py) filter in [django-rest-framework](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorestframework/0.4.0) by [Tom Christie](https://github.com/tomchristie)

On GitHub:

- [update_querystring](https://gist.github.com/1207636) by [David Gouldin](https://github.com/dgouldin)