# Django template tag to insert or replace URL parameter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is anyone aware of a Django template tag that takes the current path and query string and inserts or replaces a query string value?

e.g. given a request to /some/custom/path?q=how+now+brown+cow&page=3&filter=person

The call `{% urlparam 'page' 4 %}` would generate `/some/custom/path?q=how+now+brown+cow&page=4&filter=person`.

This wouldn't be too difficult to write from scratch, but as this seems like a very common task, I would expect a tag like this to be built-in. However, after reading through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/) and googling, I can't seem to find anyone's who's publicized such a tag.

Comment: This not a common case, its a sign of some other logic/structure issues. What's the use case for this? I mean, why are you changing the URL in the template and not fixing it the view that's rendering the template?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I strongly disagree. Consider the following case. I want to render a series of pagination links on a search page. The URL contains several query parameters (like in my example). The pagination code that renders the pagination links shouldn't have to be explicitly given all these parameters. Django's admin seems to have this behavior everywhere. Clinking one link to refine the results shouldn't lose all existing parameters.

Comment: Good use case, see my answer. I asked because sometimes a question like that is really asking for help with a solution rather than a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since I haven't used these tools by my own, I'll just refer you:

- [django-url-tools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-url-tools) has [url_params](https://bitbucket.org/monwara/django-url-tools#url-params) template tag that seems to do what you want
- [django-more-template-tags-and-filters](https://github.com/strogonoff/django-more-template-tags-and-filters) has some [helper tags](https://github.com/strogonoff/django-more-template-tags-and-filters/blob/master/more_template_tags/templatetags/more_tags.py) for manipulating urls and parameters

FYI, I've personally used [jsurl](https://github.com/Mikhus/jsurl) library for this kind of url manipulations in javascript.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it on a Django 1.3 project. Like you I expected to find this built in, but ended up coding it in the view:

```
def remove_url_param(url, params):
    if not isinstance(params, list):
        params = [params,]
    if isinstance(url, unicode):
        # urlencode doesn't like unicode
        url = url.encode('utf8')

    (scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment) = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
    param_dict = parse_qs(query)
    for p in params:
        try:
            del(param_dict[p])
        except KeyError:
            pass
    query = urllib.urlencode(param_dict, True)
    return urlparse.urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment))
```

Then I used this to create base URLs:

```
page_url_unordered = putils.remove_url_param( request.get_full_path(), ['order', 'ajax'] )
```

Then in the template:

```
<a href="{{ page_url_unordered }}&amp;order=price">Price</a>
<a href="{{ page_url_unordered }}&amp;order=size">Size</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to render a series of pagination links on a search page. The
>   URL contains several query parameters (like in my example). The
>   pagination code that renders the pagination links shouldn't have to be
>   explicitly given all these parameters. Django's admin seems to have
>   this behavior everywhere.

This is enabled by adding [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` (its not enabled by default). This will add a `request` variable to your templates, which is the [`HttpRequest` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest).

From there, you can use `{{ request.get_full_path }}` to get the current URL with the complete query string, and then append your custom query to it.

If your page is `/search?q=foo+bar`, and you want a new link to be `/search?q=foo+bar&page=4`, `<a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&page=4">page 4</a>`.

Comment: And what if your page is /search?q=foo+bar&page=1, and you want a new link to be /search?q=foo+bar&page=2    ?

Comment: Then you ask a new question :)

Comment: Yes, I know... but maybe you were aware of a simple solution. I ended up making a template tag like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/12423248/246435