# Django - TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() occurred while doing Pagination

Tags: python, django

`TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` occurs when I'm adding a pagination to a list view. This happened when I clicked `next` button to go to page 2. It should have two more results to show.

I guess it's because the value of `search` is wiped or the `queryset` becomes none somehow, when I click **next (go to page 2)**, then it returns **none**.

**Error:**
[image]

**Search Form:**
[image]

**book/views:**

```
class SearchResultView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'book/search.html'
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        search = self.request.GET.get('search')
        if search:
            return Book.objects.filter(
                title__icontains=search
            )
```

**book/templates/book.html:**

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get" action="{% url 'book:search' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <input style="font-size: 12px; width: 200px" class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Book Name" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**book/templates/search.html:**

```
<div id="customContents">
    {% block customContents %}
    {% if book_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for book in book_list %}
        <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
        {% empty %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {% if is_paginated %}

    <div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    <h3> No result found. </h3>
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

**book/urls:**

```
app_name = 'book'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('search/', views.SearchResultView.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

**It only works fine like this:**

```
class SearchResultView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'book/search.html'
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    paginate_by = 2
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(
                title__icontains='Python'
            )
```

Comment: Can you add full traceback?

Comment: You can use [Django Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/). And Instead of testing using `len()` you can simply do `if books_with_title:`.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner sure, added

Comment: You return nothing in case `search` is falsable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I removed it and changed the code, but still face the same issue

Comment: You understand it the wrong way, you should `return queryset.none()` *outside* the `if search` statement. Since it is possible (initially) that there *is no* `search` parameter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah ok, but it complains `Invalid page (2): That page contains no results`, why is the page invalid, it should have results

Comment: @Jinx: because you instruct it that way: you return an *empty* queryset.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but it should have 2 more books to display, the `return nothing statement` is just for the invalid input from users in case

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hi, I found the reason why it's not working properly. Can you take a look at the update part of my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite the `search` parameter in the query string, since you're not repeating it. There's a bunch of answers accumulated over time [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755150/altering-one-query-parameter-in-a-url-django/12968877#12968877) on how to handle that.

This is your mistake to fix:

```
<a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
```

(And the same for the "next" link).

Then everything should work as advertized.

Alternatively, you can make the search parameter part of the URL itself, but that has the side effect of making the search cacheable (which is good or bad depending on your site) and requires javascript to move the input to the url.

To do it purely in Django, you transfer the search results to a [RedirectView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.base/RedirectView/) that does nothing else but validate the search parameter and then redirect to the actual search listing.

Again, there are some side effects to that approach, most notably the effect on the back button.

So I advise you to look into querystring modification at the linked answer and if you want to go a different route, post another question with your preferences.

Comment: one of the solutions worked for me. just wondering how the `search` parameter would be overrided somehow? I don't think I change it manually

Comment: When you create a link that starts with a question mark, you effectively remove any previous query string (A.k.a. GET parameters that Django puts in a [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/)). Since your search form uses the GET method, the browser transforms the form elements to a query string, so your `search` parameter is in the query string.

Comment: that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Your `get_queryset()` method returns `None`. Because instead of passing `search` in query string your are passing `page=2`. So, your `search` your variable is `None`. If the condition fails `get_queryset()` returning `None`.

Put your `return queryset.filter(title='no result found')` outside the condition.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    search = self.request.GET.get('search')
    if search:
        books_with_title = queryset.filter(title__icontains=search)
        if len(books_with_title) > 0:
            return books_with_title

        books_with_author = queryset.filter(authors__name=search)
        if len(books_with_author) > 0:
            return books_with_author

        books_with_publisher = queryset.filter(publisher__name=search)
        if len(books_with_publisher) > 0:
            return books_with_publisher

    return queryset.filter(title='no result found')
```

Comment: @Jinx Try changing this - `search = self.request.GET.get('page')`.